# Leafletjs - How do I late-bind popups to markers?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

Ok so I have the following function:

```
    for ( var layer in this._map._layers ) {
        if ( this._map._layers[layer]._leaflet_id == id ) {
            this._map._layers[layer].bindPopup('some text').openPopup();
            continue;
        }
    }
```

It throws the following error when the popup is bound:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'
```

My thoughts on this are that the object being returned from map._layers is not a node object. Ok, so how do I get the node object for that layer?

Comment: This might actually be a dumb question. The bug was elsewhere.

Comment: I got my tumbleweed badge for this one.